# How can I change an HTML input value's data type to integer?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery to retrieve a value submitted by an input button. The value is supposed to be an integer. I want to increment it by one and display it.

```
// Getting immediate Voting Count down button id
var countUp = $(this).closest('li').find('div > input.green').attr('id');
var count = $("#"+countUp).val() + 1;
alert (count);
```

The above code gives me a concatenated string. Say for instance the value is 3. I want to get 4 as the output, but the code produces 31.

How can I change an HTML input value's data type to integer?

Comment: Side note: any text that comes from HTML is a string by default because HTML is, well, a string :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To convert `strValue` into an integer, either use:

```
parseInt(strValue, 10);
```

or the unary `+` operator.

```
+strValue
```

Note the radix parameter to `parseInt` because a leading 0 would cause `parseInt` to assume that the input was in octal, and an input of `010` would give the value of 8 instead of 10

Comment: There was a backwards incompatible change in EcmaScript which fixes the default-octal behaviour; any browser with a release in last 10 years or so parses it as decimal without an explicit `8` as second argument: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 6):

```
parseInt(  $("#"+countUp).val()  ,  10  )
```

Comment: Yes. Otherwise you get results such as `parseInt('010');` being *8*.

Comment: @ptamzz - Yes, it does. The default is "try to guess".

Answer (score 2):

Use parseInt as in: `var count = parseInt($("#"+countUp).val(), 10) + 1;` or the `+` operator as in `var count = +$("#"+countUp).val() + 1;`

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = parseInt(countUp, 10) + 1;
```

See [w3schools webpage for parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp).

Answer (score 0):

There is a [parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp) method for that or [Number](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_number.asp) constructor.