# JavaScript treats numbers as strings, not integers, and ParseInt doesn't fix it

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to insert two numbers in two input type text fields. After I do that, I have to make sure than the first number is smaller than the second. To do this, I'm capturing both fields like this:

```
var supt = $('#suptotal').val();
var supc = $('#supcubierta').val();
```

When I compare the two variables, they are strings, so for example 21 is considered bigger than 123.

I've tried to use the function `ParseInt`, like this

```
var supt = ParseInt($('#suptotal').val());
```

but it didn't work. How can I compare the numbers as numbers?

Comment: it's lowercase and you should specify a radix.

Comment: already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5327215/982924

Comment: For future reference you have the specification for the language [ECMA262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) or [Mozillas reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript) or this extremely useful [resource](http://bit.ly/Q2YCul). Good luck, and don't forget to accept an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I changed the html input value datatype to integer?? \[javascript\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327179/how-can-i-changed-the-html-input-value-datatype-to-integer-javascript)

Answer (score 5):

use `parseInt($('#suptotal').val(), 10)` as against `ParseInt($('#suptotal').val(), 10)`

The function names are case sensitive

Answer (score 2):

```
parseInt( $('#suptotal').val(), 10 );
```

Specify a radix as well, incase the string contains something like `'010'` which would be interpreted as an octal and result in 8.

Answer (score 1):

```
ParseInt($('#suptotal').val());
```

You've written the function incorrectly. `parseInt` is defined in a lowerCamelCase style.

```
parseInt($('#suptotal').val());
```

It is also advised that you specify the radix parameter with 10 for base 10.

```
parseInt($('#suptotal').val(), 10);
```

But if you are simply wanting to convert the string into a number, use the unary effect of the binary operator `+`, which will coerce a value into a number when used on a single operand:

```
var supt = +$('#suptotal').val();
```

Comment: Especially when it was originally text.

Comment: Sorry, the way my computer displays text is awful. I used images because my computer won't change the way it's shown.